# Google play console warning app is using unsupported API

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

i have uploaded my app on google play store and app reports 2 warnings

> The following APIs are grey-listed and Google can’t guarantee that they will work on existing versions of Android. Some may already be restricted for your target SDK
>
> API Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V 4
>   occurrences identified. Only unique stack trace are shown

Stack Trace 1 (APP Class in statck trace: at com.elaxer.Registration2.onCreate(Registration2.java:6))

```
     StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
        at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
        at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Class.java)
        at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.cancelPendingShow(TooltipCompatHandler.java:19)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.shouldAnimateActionModeView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:268)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.calculateNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:4)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.getMenuInflater(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.updateResourcesConfigurationForNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:4)
        at com.elaxer.Registration2.onCreate(Registration2.java:6)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Stack trace 2  (APP Class in statck trace: at com.elaxer.Splash_one.onCreate(Splash_one.java:45)

```
 StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Class.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.cancelPendingShow(TooltipCompatHandler.java:19)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.shouldAnimateActionModeView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:268)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.calculateNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:4)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.getMenuInflater(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.updateResourcesConfigurationForNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:4)
    at com.elaxer.Splash_one.onCreate(Splash_one.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

> API 
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>             2 occurrences identified. Only unique stack traces are shown.

Stack trace 1 (APP Class in statck trace:at com.elaxer.Splash_one.onCreate(Splash_one.java:45)

```
 StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Class.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.<clinit>(TooltipCompatHandler.java:23)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.cancelPendingShow(TooltipCompatHandler.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.shouldAnimateActionModeView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:268)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.calculateNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:4)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.getMenuInflater(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.updateResourcesConfigurationForNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:0)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:4)
    at com.elaxer.Splash_one.onCreate(Splash_one.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I am using following library in gradle

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.1"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.0'

implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.0'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'


implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0'
```

I don't find a way to fix this warnings.Please help me to get rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is using [makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#1508) method (directly or via embedded libs) which is a [non-SDK method/hidden method](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

There are many ways to detect the problematic usage with [Test your app for non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#test-for-non-sdk). The easiest ones are [veridex tool](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#test-veridex-tool) or [use StrictMode API](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#test-strictmode-api).

How to use strict mode : [Create strict mode object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) and use `detectNonSdkApiUsage` and `penaltyListener`.

```
public void onCreate() {
     if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());

         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectNonSdkApiUsage()
                 .penaltyListener( Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() , new StrictMode.OnVmViolationListener(){...} )
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
     }
     super.onCreate();
 }
```

Note: Make sure to use  Android 9 (API level 28) to test and verify the issue.

> Starting in Android 9 (API level 28), the platform restricts which
>   non-SDK interfaces your app can use

Comment: Great so you detect it, but no one seems to know how to fix some of these that are inside google SDKs.  Like the compute window size one. and so on...